# PHP exec() Throttling

Tags: php, exec, throttling

I have a webpage that, if some data is missing, I run an exec command to gather the data I need. It all works great, the issue I want to try to avoid is if someone spams my site with the wrong kinds of urls and runs this call thousands of times.

I am removing potential items in the call, but I would really like it if I could limit the call to, say once every 5 seconds, no matter who makes the call. IE, the first call goes through fine, but if someone else tries during that time it would not allow it for the set amount of time.

I wouldn't mind adding a tar to it later, ie if the next call is under 5 seconds increase to 10 seconds, etc, but for now I just want to add a safety throttle on the call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a ["Lock" or a "Mutex"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science))

> In computer science, a lock or mutex (from mutual exclusion) is a synchronization mechanism for enforcing limits on access to a resource in an environment where there are many threads of execution. A lock is designed to enforce a mutual exclusion concurrency control policy.

There are a couple of libraries out there that take care of this for you and I would encourage you to use those, if this is an option.

- [Symfony Lock](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html)
- [php-lock/lock](https://github.com/php-lock/lock)

PHP has/had a [mutex implementation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mutex.php) but I believe (if I understand things correctly) it is only for CLI applications because it came from the optional pthreads extension.

If you want to roll your own, you could literally just use a file on disk. If that file exists, you know that a process is running and other requests should abort/do something else. Once the running process is complete, you just need to delete that special file. You should also register an [error handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and/or [shutdown function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) who guarantees that the file is deleted, just in case your exec logic throws a fatal exception.

The actual file isn't important, it could just be `/tmp/my-app-lock` but it is common in *nux to put these in `/var/run` or similar, *if* your process has access to it. You could also just put this in your website's folder, too.

Instead of a file, you could also use a database with the same idea. If a value exists, it should assume to be locked. If it isn't, the caller should create the value in a transaction (to guarantee that it exists). Maybe even uses a shared key but a unique per-process random value that double-checks that it actually acquired the lock. This is actually built into the Symfony version, too, as one of their locks.

**edit**

Here's an example using Symfony's lock component:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Lock\LockFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\FlockStore;

// the argument is the path of the directory where the locks are created
// if none is given, sys_get_temp_dir() is used internally.
$store = new FlockStore('/var/stores');
$factory = new LockFactory($store);

$lock = $factory->createLock('pdf-invoice-generation');

if ($lock->acquire()) {
    // The resource "pdf-invoice-generation" is locked.
    // You can compute and generate invoice safely here.

    $lock->release();
}
```

Also, Symfony's lock component doesn't require the entire Symfony framework, it is standalone.